# How many ways are there to get from the origin to $(c,d)$ while avoiding $(a,b)$ using only upward and rightward moves?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> For natural numbers $0\lt a\le b \lt c\le d$ count the number of ways to get from the point $(0,0)$ to $(c,d)$ without going through the point $(a,b)$ using only East (right 1 unit) and North (up 1 unit) steps.

**GUESS 1:**

Can I simply count the ways to get from $(0,0)$ to $(c,d)$ ***no restrictions*** and then subtract off the ways to get from $(0,0)$ to $(a,b)$?
That would look like a multi-set permutation for $\{E^c,N^d\}$ and subtracting a permutation for $\{E^a,N^b\}$:

$$\frac{(c+d)!}{c!\cdot d!}-\frac{(a+b)!}{a!\cdot b!}$$

**GUESS 2:**

I also *think* that going through $(a,b)$ on the way to $(c,d)$ is the same as picking a path to $(a,b)$ and then going to $(c,d)$ from there. This is why maybe I'd take the number of ways to get from $(0,0)$ to $(c,d)$ ***no restrictions*** and then subtract the number of ways to get from $(0,0)$ to $(a,b)$ along with the path from there to $(c,d)$:

$$\frac{(c+d)!}{c!\cdot d!}-\frac{(a+b)!}{a!\cdot b!}\color{red}{\bigg(\frac{(c-a+d-b)!}{(c-a)!\cdot (d-b)!}\bigg)}$$

I think **GUESS 2** is more likely to be correct because going from $(0,0)$ to $(2,2)$ avoiding $(1,1)$ doesn't mean we just subtract off the $2$ ways to get to $(1,1)$.

Comment: Guess 2 is correct.

Comment: Here is my way to figure out that Method 2 is Correct : [[ Number of ways to go from Origin to Destination must Equal Number of ways to go from Destination to Origin : Check that Method 1 gives Different (wrong) Answer in that Case , while Method 2 gives Same (Correct) Answer ]]

Comment: @RobPratt yes but not as explicitly as my formula

Comment: Just curious, why don’t you use binomial coefficient instead of explicit factorials? Much more readable that way

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja I'm not used to using them for multi-set permutations I guess. I just started combinatorics a few weeks ago, and I'm interested in using this for calculations

Comment: Fair enough, although binomial coefficient is the most widely used in combinatorics problem at this kind of level, so it’d be good to learn about them. E.g. you need $c+d$ steps from origin to $(c,d)$, and $c$ of these steps are east steps, so there are $\binom{c+d}{c}$ paths

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Yeah I know about it, didn’t think to use it